# FPGA(DE0 Nano) trying to connect with VGA but gets a Short Circuit

Tags: fpga, vga

I am trying to connect my DE0 Nano FPGA to an display by using VGA.
The output ports of the DE0 Nano have a voltage of 3.3, but the RGB Signals of the VGA want 0,7 V so I used a voltage divider.

I found this pinout for the VGA:
[Pin Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apIv8.gif)
Ive got a simple program that the RGB Signals are constant "1", so that the screen should give me white. The RGB signals are 0,7 V when they are not connected to the screen. When i connect the cable to the screen a short circuit appears, and on RGB I've  got 0 V..

```
Red Signal > Pin 1
Green Signal > Pin 2
Blue Signal > Pin 3
H_Sync Signal > Pin 13
V_Sync Signal > Pin 14
GND Signal > Pin 5
```

Does anybody have an idea what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ive solved the problem, i made a voltage divider to make sure there is 0,7 Volt on the RGB signals. But i used resistors in the k range, so my current was being limited. This made my voltage go to zero..